# Sequence that converges point wise

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x^n)$ with $0\leq x\leq 1$ converges pointwise to the function zero but not converges uniformly.

I tried to get the maximum and then take the limit but I only discover that the maximum in all function is $1/4$. How can I prove this pointwise convergence and not uniformly convergence. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f(x)=0$ is the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$, let's notice that $x^n \rightarrow 0$ for all $x\in [0, 1)$, and also, $1-x^n<1$, such that if $x\in [0,1)$, then $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$. Now for all $n$, we have that $f_n(1)=0$, and therefore $f_n(1)\rightarrow 0$, such that the function converges pointwise to $0$ in $[0,1]$.

Let $f(x)=0$ to be the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$. Notice that $f_n'(x)=nx^{n-1}(1-x^n)-nx^{n-1}x^n=nx^{n-1}(1-2x^{n})$. Notice that this is equal to 0 when $x=0$ or when $x=(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Let's look at $f_n((\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{n}})=((\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{n}})^n(1-((\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{n})^n)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{4}\neq 0$, and therefore we found a series $x_n=(\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{n}$, such that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n=1$ such that $f_n(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $f(1)=0$. Therefore there's no uniform convergence.

Comment: The wording used in this proof is quite awkward. You cannot say "Let's write $f(x)=0$ to be the limit of $f_n(x)$". First of all, you didn't specify what kind of limit (pointwise, uniform...) and second of all, you don't even know if the limit exists yet (and it indeed does not).

Answer (score 1):

You have already shown, more or less, that the function does not converge to $0$ uniformly, because the maximum of $f_n$ is $\frac14$ for all values of $n$ (you should still write a couple of lines to explain how this means that uniform convergence is not possible, but the lines should be clear).

To prove that the sequence converges pointwise, you simply need to pick an arbitrary $x$ and prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n(1-x^n)=0$$

which should be easy, since $(1-x^n) < 1$ and $x^n\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.